# Data table search is not working when we have more than one data table in same page

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using data-tables plugin to show my data in a model box. In my page, we have 2 data-tables the second search input is working fine but the first search input is not working.

1st table code:

```
$('#target-predictions').DataTable({
    scrollY:'200px',
    scrollX:false,
    scrollCollapse:true,
});
$('#target-predictions_filter').find('input').attr('type','token');
```

2nd table code:

```
$('#ae-table tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="token" class="column-input" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
});

var table = $('#ae-table').DataTable({
    scrollY:'400px',
    scrollCollapse:true,
});
table.draw();

table.columns().every( function () {
    var column = this
    $( '.column-input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( column.search() !== this.value ) {
            column.search( this.value ).draw();
        }
   });
});
$('#ae-table_filter').find('input').attr('type','token');
```

Comment: May be both have same id.

Comment: no, both are different

Comment: please post the code

Comment: Is data table present within model?

Comment: yes both are in a modelbox

Comment: Just of curiosity: Why the `.attr('type','token')`'s ...?

Comment: to make the search input as a box instead of line. we wrote CSS to type token... that's it